# nginx ssl_preread configuration not redirecting requests to a upstream

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, puppet, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx between puppet agents  and two puppet masters . say puppetmaster1 and puppetmaster2

so the connection flow that is expected is

puppetagent1 ->> Nginx ->> puppetmaster1 &

puppetagent2 ->> Nginx ->> puppetmaster2

**puppetmaster1 and puppetagent1 runs on puppet version- 2.7.26**

**puppetmaster2 and puppetagent2 runs on puppet version- 3.6.2**

Here is my nginx stream.conf that does a proxy pass to the upstream

```
map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
puppetmaster1  upstream_puppetmaster1;
puppetmaster2  upstream_puppetmaster2;
```

}

```
upstream upstream_puppetmaster1 {
     server core-services_puppetmaster1:8140;
    }

 upstream upstream_puppetmaster2 {
     server core-services_puppetmaster2:8140;
    }


server {
    listen                8140;
    ssl_preread           on;
    proxy_pass            $name;
  }
```

Issue:
When puppet agnet -tov is  run on the **puppetagent2**  the Nginx redirects it to **upstream_puppetmaster2** and everything works fine
But when puppet agnet -tov is  run on the puppetagent1 the  Nginx errors out with the  below log

```
2018/09/11 17:38:11 [info] 25#25: *3 client 10.255.0.2:51290 connected to 0.0.0.0:8140
2018/09/11 17:38:11 [error] 25#25: *3 no host in upstream "", client: 10.255.0.2, server: 0.0.0.0:8140, bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

The only difference between puppetmaster1 and puppetmaster2 is version

Can anyone help me figure out why nginx is not able to serve requests from puppetagent1 and pass it to puppetmaster1 ? 
How can i achieve this ?

Thanks in Advance